SpringDevTools does not restart REST Endpoint
I'd need to restart my REST Endpoints when I change the implementation. Therefore, I have added to my Spring Boot 3 project spring-boot-devtools.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

However, it seems to have no effect on my REST Endpoint. If I edit them and save nothing happens:
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Welcome"; // Changing has no effect
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Is spring-boot-devtools supposed to restart my application when I modify and save a REST Endpoint or generally a @Component?
Thanks

This question is similar to: spring-boot-devtools Automatic Restart not working. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In case you are using IntelliJ two additional settings have to be enabled:

Settings -> Build, execution, deployment -> Compiler -> Select “Build Project automatically”
Settings -> Advanced a settings -> Select “Allow auto make…”

After that it should work

Yes, spring-boot-devtools help with automatic restarts of Spring Boot application when you make any changes to code, including REST endpoints and other @Components

Thanks. Did I miss any configuration then? I have tried adding without success: spring.devtools.restart.pollInterval=1s
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
